# AOSP : what files to edit in order to change core system styles?

Tags: android, android-source, theming

I need to be able to change the default system styling found in KitKat and apply a custom theme but running into a bit of a issue where the styles don't seem to propagate once I build AOSP and flash onto the device.

From what I can tell, I should be editing either

1. styles.xml
2. styles_device_defaults.xml
3. themes.xml
4. themes_device_defaults.xml

I've tried applying changes to all four files. Things build fine, but the changes never show up for some reason.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, it was a server-related issue beyond my control. The guys dealing with the server setup did something weird.

I had two copies of the source, one just for my own testing and one for everyone to use and build from. The files from my copies were basically overwriting everything whenever you wanted to make a build in the main general build area.